# Matrix Norm Lemma

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

There is a lemma claims that :
$||Ax||/||x|| \le max_{||x||\ne 0} (||Ax||/||x|)  = ||A|| $

I'd like to know how come $||Ax||/||x|| \le max_{||x||\ne 0} (||Ax||/||x|)$
because it does not make sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The claim is false.

Comment: It's not false if you stipulate that $\|x\| \leq 1$. Does the question do this @itamar?

Comment: @Frank ,thanks for the answer , but that claim (as i've seen at) does not assume that $||x|| \le 1 $

Comment: And does the matrix $A$ have any special properties? As state it's false. Of course equality is true (this is a definition), but the inequality should be $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\|\|x\|$).

Comment: @Frank , i've just noticed that i haven't wrote the inequality correctly. Now  it's fixed.

Comment: Lol, OK, phew!!

Comment: Please see my answer now, which hopefully answers your question.

Comment: With the edit, the claim is no longer false, but now all it says is that any number from a set is less than or equal to the maximum element from the set. Does that really need a lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\|A\| := \sup\{ \|Aw\| : \|w\| = 1\} \geq \|Ay\|$$

for all $y$ with $\|y\| = 1$. But for any $x \neq 0$, we know that $y:= \dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$ has norm $1$. So substituing this choice of $y$ into the above inequality gives the required result.